# Sending a complete lang file to a view [CodeIgniter]

Tags: codeigniter

Is there any way to send a complete lang file to a view, so that I can access the `$lang`-variable inside the view.

At the moment the only thing I can find is sending seperate lines to the view (using `$this->lang->line('lang_key')`) which sounds very antagonizing if I have a few dozen lines I want to print in the view.

My question is if there's a way to select a specific language file and make the whole `$lang` array in that language file accessible from a view.

Comment: Load the language helper & use the 'lang' function e.g: <?php echo lang('USERNAME'); ?> to get the translation or <?php echo lang('USERNAME', 'username'); ?> to get a label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you view in order to see all your lang array.

```
print_r($this->lang);
```

Comment: This prints the whole $lang array as well as which language files has been loaded.  
Seems a bit redundant having to copy the whole $lang variable to a $data variable which I later send tot the view in every controller. Is there no other way to "connect" views to lang files? It feels like I'm using the lang-class the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You should put :

```
$this->load->lang('your lang file name');
```

in the constructor of the controller from which you load your view.

and use it in the view as :

```
<?php lang->line('key');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the translation file in the constructor:

```
$this->lang->load('trans_file', 'spanish');
```

An then on the view, you can echo each line by:

```
<?php echo $this->lang->line('prod_not_found'); ?>
```